# Is it possible to enable flyspell in scratch buffers?

Tags: flyspell

I often use scratch buffers, when I want to take a closer look at some code. However I can't enable `flyspell` in scratch buffers. Is there a way to also use it when not editing a file ?

**EDIT:**

I can't enable `flyspell-mode` while the buffer isn't saved to a file. When I use it in a scratch buffer I only get this message in the echo area `Flyspell mode disabled in current buffer`. No matter how often I try to activate it.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to lawlist I found the problem. It seems, that I ignored `flyspell-lazy-mode` consequently while I was looking for the problem.

> This package also forces flyspell-mode off completely for certain
>   buffers.

"Certain buffers" seems to include scratch buffers, but not buffers that are attached to a file. lawlist was right so I reward his correct answer and also his patience.

Comment: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)`  As mentioned in the comment to my answer below, Emacs permits enabling `flyspell-mode` in a non-file-visiting-buffer -- there is no need to ever save the buffer to use `flyspell-mode` (unless of course you want to save the buffer).  If you cannot enable `flyspell-mode` in a non-file-visiting-buffer, then recursively bisect your user-configuration by commenting stuff out and restarting Emacs until you find the culprit for the non-default behavior.  No one will be able to guess what is in your user-configuration that may be causing the need to save.

Comment: The following is an alternative approach that does not require using a major-mode hook.  `(defun python-scratch () (interactive) (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*python-scratch*")) (python-mode) (flyspell-mode 1))`  This example works with no user-configuration whatsoever except `(setq ispell-program-name "/path/to/your/spelling/program/such/as/aspell")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default major-mode for the `*Scratch*` buffer is `lisp-interaction-mode`.  In this example, we use the `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` -- `lisp-interaction-mode` is *derived* from `emacs-lisp-mode`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

---

Another method is to use the `lisp-interaction-mode-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

---

Another method is to call `flyspell-mode` manually with:  `M-x flyspell-mode`

Comment: This does not work with `flyspell-mode`. I can't even enable it manually. But as soon as I have saved the buffer it works.

Comment: Flyspell works out-of-the-box on a non-file-visiting-buffer such as `*Scratch*`.  To test this theory, open Emacs 25 without any user configuration whatsoever -- e.g., `emacs -q`.  Go to the `*Scratch*` buffer.  Then, type `M-x eval-expression RET (setq ispell-program-name "/path/to/your/spelling/program/such/as/aspell") RET`.  Then type `M-x flyspell-mode` and have fun.  If your current user-configuration is causing a conflict, then you may wish to recursively bisect it by commenting stuff out until you find the problem.

Comment: When you see a message "*Flyspell mode **disabled** in current buffer*", that means it was already **enabled** (i.e., *it was already running*) and you **disabled** it.  One way to check whether `flyspell-mode` is running, is to type `M-x describe-mode` and see the listing in the `*Help*` buffer (at the very top) of all minor modes that are active.

Comment: No because I would also see that it is enabled after I disabled it in the echo area. It only shows the message that it is disabled. But thanks for the hint with `emacs -q`. I removed every line of config related to `flyspell` and it still won't work. And it seems a little odd to me, that it works when I save the buffer ?

Comment: Removing whatever you believe is relevant from your user-configuration is *not* the best way to troubleshoot whether something in your user-configuration is causing problems that differ from the default behavior of Emacs 25.  To truly test how Emacs 25 behaves by default, you should try it *without* any user-configuration whatsoever -- i.e., nothing, zip, zero, zilch, nada.  :)  If you cannot achieve the results described in the second comment, then your Emacs installation is likely broken somehow.